# Solving an algebraic equation for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of $x$, what is the value of $x$ in this equation, step by step solution will be great.
\begin{equation}
0.4x+15=x
\end{equation}

Comment: is this $.4$ as $0.4$ right?

Answer (score 3):

As your asking for help on such a simple question.  I'll explain each step

Starting with the original equation

$$0.4 x + 15 = x$$

First we want to get the 15 on its own which we can do by subracting $0.4 x$ from the left had side (LHS) of the equation because we do that on the LHS we need to do it to right hand side too; otherwise the equation no-longer balances.

$$\begin{align}
0.4 x + 15 & = x \\
0.4 x + 15 - 0.4 x & = x - 0.4 x \\
15 &= x - 0.4 x
\end{align}$$

Now we note that $ x = 1x$ so

$$\begin{align}
15 &= x - 0.4 x \\
   &= 1x - 0.4x \\
   &= x(1-0.4) \\
   &= 0.6 x \\
\frac{15}{0.6} & = x \\
 x &= \frac{15}{0.6} \\
 x &= 25
\end{align}$$

This is the same result as given by dato and his answer is correct.  I've just added a few extra steps to make it (I hope) a little clearer.

The key point to remember is that what you do to the LHS of the equation you also have to do to the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

So we have,

$15=x-0.4x$

$15=0.6x$

$x=\frac{15}{0.6}=25$

Because,

$$\frac{15}{0.6}=\frac{15}{\frac{6}{10}}=\frac{(15\cdot 10)}{6}=\frac{150}{6}=25$$